# Can We Use Steam Web Api For Classic Asp?

Tags: asp-classic, steam-web-api

I am new to Asp Classic, and we have this request to integrate Steam Payment for web.

Is it possible?

Added this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Buy BanaCash</title> 
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" target="_new" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"    name="form1" action="https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamMicroTxnSandbox/InitTxn/v3/?key=#################&format=json" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="orderid" name="orderid" value="938473"/>  
            <input type="hidden" id="steamid" name="steamid" value="################"/>    
            <input type="hidden" id="appid" name="appid" value="######"/> 
            <input type="hidden" id="itemcount" name="itemcount" value="1"/>   
            <input type="hidden" id="language" name="language" value="EN"/>   
            <input type="hidden" id="currency" name="currency" value="USD"/>  
            <!--input type="hidden" id="usersession" name="usersession" value="web"/>  
            <input type="hidden" id="ipaddress" name="ipaddress" value="127.0.0.1"/-->    
            <input type="hidden" id="itemid[0]" name="itemid[0]" value="12345"/> 
            <input type="hidden" id="qty[0]" name="qty[0]" value="1"/>   
            <input type="hidden" id="amount[0]" name="amount[0]" value="1000"/>   
            <input type="hidden" id="description[0]" name="description[0]" value="10000TCoin"/>  
            <input type="hidden" id="category[0]" name="category[0]" value="TCoin"/>  

</form>
</body>
<script>
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
</script>
</html>
```

Steam Web Api reply:

```
{
"response": {
    "result": "Failure",
    "params": {
        "orderid": "938473"
    },
    "error": {
        "errorcode": 7,
        "errordesc": "User ############ not logged in"
    }
}
}
```

as you can see on the reply i am getting an error

Comment: You should better describe what help you need. A working example or some help finding corresponding information or technical clarification overview or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, sorry for that, what i need if possible is some working sample using InitTxn and FinalizeTxn

Comment: Start here: https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html#ISteamMicroTxn_InitTxn_v3 and here https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html#ISteamMicroTxn_FinalizeTxn_v2

Comment: thank you for this link, i already found this link and as you can see on the code, i was able to do the post transaction, but unfortunately i got an error . I tried to login my account first on steam but still having the same error

Comment: @Jaguanta did you find a solution? I came into the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error text (`User ############ not logged in`) when integrating Steam In-Game Purchasing. In my case Steam client was logged in but not to the game provided in `ISteamMicroTxn/InitTxn` method. When running game in development mode there has to be `steam_appid.txt` file with steam game id inside. I had this file in my project but with wrong value inside (from other game). During tests with development game version be sure that steam game id value inside `steam_appid.txt` on client side is equal to `appid` parameter in `ISteamMicroTxn/InitTxn` method